# if condition in for loop in twig template engine

Tags: symfony, twig

Every company object is with a one-to-many relation with image.
Now in my template I want to check if there is an image of type testtype.

How to handle this with twig? The following gives me an exception:

> Unexpected token "string" of value "testtype" ("name" expected)

Twig

```
{% for image in company.images if image.type is 'testtype' %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you tried a simple `if image.type == 'testtype'`?

Comment: Do you want to iterate over all company objects or just the ones with `image.type` "testtype"? If you want to iterate over all objects and just do a special output for the `testtype` images you could put the if in your for loop. `{% if image.type == 'testtype' %}` should work

Comment: i just want to iterate over one object which has the property type = 'givenstring'

Comment: Why do you pass all objects to your view if you just want one single object?

Comment: the reason is that i have a company which contains three pictures.. top, middle and bottom picture.. which i defined with types.. now i need in the top position the top picture in the middle the middle one and so on...i dont wanted to save the pictures in the company table thats the reason why i have oneToMany here

Comment: Hmm sorry I've no other ideas at the moment. Maybe provide some details so others can help or understand besser what you'd like to achieve?

Answer (score 22):

The [new way to do that](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html#filter) is the following ([`for if` is deprecated since Twig 2.10](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/deprecated.html#tags)):

```
{% for image in company.images|filter(image => image.type is 'testtype') %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 12):

warning: this answer is already deprecated

```
<ul>
{% for user in users if user.active %}
    <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition

Comment: For some reason I got an undefined error if I try and do it like this, but it works if I do the if before the for.

Comment: Looks like this has been removed in Twig v3, without any deprecation info

Comment: Just found this [Deprecated Features page](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/deprecated.html#tags) which says: 

"Adding an if condition on a for tag is deprecated in Twig 2.10. Use a filter filter or an "if" condition inside the "for" body instead (if your condition depends on a variable updated inside the loop)"

Answer (score 5):

did you try this

```
{% for myimage in company.images %}
   {% if myimage.type == 'testtype' %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as `testtype` is a string, then I would try:

```
{% for image in company.images if image.type == 'testtype' %}
```

Comment: Adding an if condition on a for tag is deprecated in Twig 2.10. Use a filter filter or an “if” condition inside the “for” body instead (if your condition depends on a variable updated inside the loop). https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/deprecated.html#tags